# angular ng-loop dynamic input and dynamic value to data processing

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to create a dynamic form in angular. if `type` is `text`, the input will be `<input type="text">`. If `type` is `checkbox`, it will display `<input type="checkbox">`

here is the data successfully requested from server that i put in controller `$scope`

```
.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.form_data = [
       {"id":1,"question":"Name","type":"text","user_criteria":"faiz","answer":[]},
       {"id":5,"question":"Hair Type","type":"checkbox","user_criteria":"Long","answer":[{"id_answer":10,"id_survey":5,"answer_txt":"Long"},{"id_answer":11,"id_survey":5,"answer_txt":"Short"}]}
    ];

    $scope.updated_form = {};
});
```

this is the template

```
<div ng-repeat="fm in form_data">
    <div ng-if="fm.type =='text'">
        <label>{{fm.question}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="{{fm.user_criteria}}">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="fm.type =='checkbox'">
        <div ng-repeat="ans in fm.answer">
            <input type="checkbox"> {{ans.answer_txt}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for the input type `text` value. it appears `label` print `Name` and the input `value` print `faiz`. the code are displayed successfully to the correct input type and value.

but i have 2 question.

1. is there a way in the checkbox to check the value of the `user_criteria` to `check` the `checkbox` input?
2. how to pass all this data into the `$scope.updated_form` so i can use the value from the input like this ?

   ```
   $scope.updated_form = [
       {"id":1, "user_criteria": "faiz new name"},
       {"id":5, "user_criteria": "Short"}
   ];
   ```

i am stuck to pass the form data for processing since i am lost when it comes to `nested loop` in the `checkbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small sample to resolve your issues:

http://jsbin.com/pahuwe/3/edit?html,js,output

I used a initial fill function, to transfer the data to updated_form field:

```
$scope.updated_form = [];
$scope.form_data.forEach(function(item) {
    $scope.updated_form.push(item);
});
```

and I used input radio for select, but with model and value parameters:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="fm.user_criteria" ng-value="ans.id_answer"/>
```

Use a same ng-model to permit select a unique response.

Comment: `forEach` and `ng-model="fm.user_criteria" ng-value="ans.id_answer"` is what i was looking for. this solve it

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, you want to know what user checked and inputted , you can use another model to store the user data.(You need to init the `updated_form` with ids) And for the checkbox, you need to add a function with ng-change to set the checked answer into related data. It will be like

```
<div ng-repeat="fm in form_data">
<div ng-if="fm.type =='text'">
    <label>{{fm.question}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="{{updated_form[fm.id].user_criteria}}">
</div>
<div ng-if="fm.type =='checkbox'">
    <div ng-repeat="ans in fm.answer">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="theChecked" ng-change=" if (theChecked) updated_form[fm.id].user_criteria = ans.answer_txt; "> {{ans.answer_txt}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i used  `ng-model="{{updated_form[fm.id].user_criteria}}"` in the input text. the value becomes null. but if i use mine `{{fm.user_criteria}}` the value are displayed in the text field

Comment: Yes, I said you should initialize the `updated_form` data to set its id and  user_criteria value.